# How to force Spring Boot to use Tomcat server in integration tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use default Tomcat embedded container. However, in some of my tests I use Wiremock (using Jetty underneath). This makes my integration tests run against Jetty server, not Tomcat.

Is there any way to force Spring Boot to stick with Tomcat ?

Comment: Check wire mock version, I updated for the last one and it worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Stéphane Nicoll stated [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5350) you should define an empty `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` `@Bean`

Simply adding such bean was not sufficient for me. I got 'multiple beans' exception. As I was adding that to a custom test starter I just had to make sure, it is added before `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` resolution took place, i.e:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ForceTomcatAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat() {
         return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    }
}
```

Edit: In Spring Boot 2.0 this works for me:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ForceTomcatAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat() {
         return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607828/netty-server-isnt-used-in-spring-boot-2-with-reactive-starter. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 2.3 the above solution hasn't worked for me.

Perhaps I have special circumstances with not having a `SpringBootApplication` in the main classes. I have only a `SpringBootApplication` in the test classes.

Anyhow this has worked for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.class)
public class TestApplication {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with Spring Boot 2.5.10

```java
@AutoConfigureBefore(ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
```

didn't work for me.

but as sven doring mentioned excluding `EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration` worked for me.
it even worked for external tomcat

code is below

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.class)
```