# Netty Server isn't used in Spring Boot 2 with Reactive starter

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm developing a reactive project using Spring Boot 2 and reactive starters. My problem is that when I start the app, the Tomcat server it's started instead of Netty.

Here is my dependencies task from build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:${springBootVersion}")
compile group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock', version: '2.15.0'
compile("ro.orange.omoney:lms-token-client:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
```

}

Can you tell me why I face this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: What is spring boot version - I have a similar config  springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'. I see o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080

Comment: The last version of Spring Boo

Comment: I've checked and I also have the Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project depends on `spring-boot-starter-hateoas`, which depends on `spring-boot-starter-web`, which depends on `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`. The final dependency causes that Tomcat is configured to run the application.

In general, you would have to exclude `spring-boot-starter-web` explicitely to bypass Tomcat auto-configuration.

Though, in this particular case, I believe it won't help as `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` project doesn't support web on reactive stack yet (in Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE).

It seems that it's either HATEOAS or reactive web at the moment.

See [HATEOAS on Spring Flux/Mono response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650753/hateoas-on-spring-flux-mono-response) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've already try to exclude the spring-boot-starter-tomcat or the spring-boot-starter web, but I'm facing multiple compilation errors, because I need some dependencies from these two starters. It seems that HATEOAS and WebFlux aren't yet compatible in the same project ...